# Multiple textFields in UITableView update the wrong textField when textFieldShouldReturn

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, becomefirstresponder

I'm doing a form through a UITableView, using custom `UITableViewCell`s which contain a `UITextField` each.

I'm using `textFieldShouldReturn` to jump to the next textField but I cannot understand why what I typed in one textField appears randomly (actually, there is weird pattern) into another textField.

Here the custom UITableViewCell

```swift
class RPTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: DictionaryTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        titleLabel.textColor = Constants.secondaryColor
        textField.textColor = Constants.secondaryColor
        contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        errorLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    func setTag(tag: Int) {
        textField.tag = 100 + tag
    }
}
```

Then in my `FormViewController` I do

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let field = formFields?[indexPath.row] else { return UITableViewCell() }        
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID") as? RPTableViewCell {
        cell.titleLabel.text = field["displayText"]?.uppercased
        cell.textField.text = field["userAnswer"] as? String // This was missing, but is key
        cell.textField.placeholder = field["placeholder"] as? String
        cell.setTag(tag: indexPath.row)
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RPTableViewCell else { return }
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
        cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let nextTextField = tableView.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: IndexPath(row: textField.tag - 100, section: 0), animated: false)
            tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: textField.tag - 99, section: 0),
                                animated: false, scrollPosition: .middle)
            nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return false
    }
```

EDIT:

In `viewDidLoad` I load the `formFiels` like this

```
// Read from a JSON file
guard let visitorPaths = Constants.configDict()?["visitorPaths"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] else {
        print("Error: no visitorPaths found in the configuration")
        return
    }
formFields = visitorPaths.first!["fields"]! as? [[String: AnyObject]]
```

Comment: It has to do with how tableView.dequeueReusableCells() works. In your cellForRowAt() method you're not setting the text of the textField. So as the cell gets reused it shows whatever was there before.

Comment: I would suggest you to use static table views for this

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will try to make a static table programmatically, since the number of form entries, thus the number of rows, may change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using the following snippet which does not work:

```
if let nextTextField = tableView.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField
```

The textfield is not a subview of your tableView. The Textfield is a subview of the TableViewCell.

You can acces the cell in the textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) delegate method like the following:

```
let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(row: textField.tag + 1, section: 0)

if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: nextIndexPath) as? RPTableViewCell {
    cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

**Edit** for the text jumping:
Add the following textField delegate method to store the new text:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    formFields?[textField.tag - 100]["displayText"] = textField.text
}
```

Comment: I tried both, but the problem is the same. I think the two methods are equivalent. Apple says in `viewWithTag` documentation: "This method searches the current view and all of its subviews for the specified view."
Indeed the focus jumps to the correct next textField. It is the text of the previous textField that jumps somewhere else.

Comment: @JohnnyParafango can you please add the code where you set the text to the formFields object?

Comment: I think you are not storing the new text the user typed in. Please check and try my edit

Comment: yes I know that I'm not storing the text the user typed in, but the example you wrote in your edit doesn't fit in my case. Each cell consists in a UILabel (`titleLabel = formFields[indexPath.row]["displayText"]` and an empty textField, with a placeholder, if it exists. So `displayText` is actually the entry field title label. But I can try to add another key "answer" and set it as `textField.text`

Comment: It works! But please add your answer like this: in `tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt indexPath:)` I should add something like `cell.textField.text = formFields[indexPath.row]["userAnswer"]`, where at start userAnswer is clearly empty or nil, then, in your edit please replace `displayText` with `userAnswer`